# Chrome not rendering CSS with wrong mime-types

Tags: google-chrome, css, mime-types

Certain web pages incorrectly serve CSS with text/plain or text/html mime-types. This causes Chrome not to render any style at all.

A few big sites like gizmag.com are affected, as well as smaller ones. Basically, I want Chrome to disregard mime type, when loading a style-sheet.

I know that in a perfect world, the author of the web page is in charge of writing correct code, but for certain websites, I simply can not read the content and it's been that way for months.

Example sites:
http://www.gizmag.com/
http://www.cad-comic.com/

Just to be clear, my request headers have:
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1

The response is:
Content-Type:text/html